# Can I make this for loop and if statement more concise with a stream?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

My code works fine but I want to get practice with Java 8 streams. I was wondering if I can use a stream for this?

quoteOrders is a list of order objects that implement `IOrder`. If the data is something like `bookOrder` the `if` statement will be `true` for that object and then `return bookOrder.handleOrderRequest(data)`.

```
For(IOrder order: quoteOrders){
        if(order.hasRequest(data)){
                return order.handleOrderRequest(data);
        }
}
```

I thought about maybe changing it to something like but I am not sure how to add the return statement part or if it is even possible with streams.

```java
return quoteOrders.forEach(quoteOrder -> { quoteOrders.stream().filter(order -> order.hasRequest(data))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `filter` to emulate the `if` statement, and then return the `findFirst` of the stream:

```java
return quoteOrders.stream()
                  .filter(order -> order.hasRequest(data))
                  .findFirst()
                  .map(order -> order.handleOrderRequest(data))
                  .orElse(null); // or some other default behavior
```